# Bevel Modifier: apply before or after UV unwrapping and texturing (especially on Substance Painter)?

Tags: texturing, uv, bevel

Say I made something in blender using **Hardops** and **BoxCutter** we got nice bevels, no overlapping, normals are correct. Then I apply all the cutters for **UV unwrapping and texturing in Substance Painter** and then I come across the **Bevel modifier**...

**Choices:**

**A)** Should I **apply the *Bevel* modifier**? (set at 3 levels) then tediously mark seams and UV unwrap? Or is there a better approach to this?

**B)** Mark seams and unwrap **ignoring the *Bevel* modifier**, then texture stuff in Substance Painter and go back to Blender and **reapply the *Bevel* modifier**? Will the textures be fine by that? (especially edge scratches or grunge or anything sensitive to the edge?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the bezel modifier will change the shape of your faces and add more (when applied), thereby changing the way the faces align with your UVMap. You may get lucky and find it works, but the more complicated the model and textures, the more change the bevel makes and the more likely you will need to adjust the UVMapping if not the source image. When you tediously mark seems, [look up how to "Select more faces" and "Loop selection"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html), you may also consider saving specific vertex groups so you can select one point and then "Object Properties" > "Vertext Groups" > [Pick your Group] > Click "Select". Ok, now the best part, once the Vertex Group is created, before you bevel, the bevel operation will include all the new vertex in the Vertex Group and you have a way to select all by Vertext Group ;) Now, UVMap and texture and if you have to edit the texture/vertex again, you only had to do the tedious part once